# Get Location of SCCM 2012 Task Sequence using wmi c#

Tags: c#, wmi, wmi-query, sccm

I'm trying to identify the location a task sequence sits using wmi so that I can only get particular task sequences that are stored in a particular sub folder.

For example in SCCM configuration manager under "Software Library>Overview>Operating Systems>Task Sequences" I have a folder called "LIVE" this is where task sequences I want to query sit. The problem I have is there are also a number of other folders that contain task sequences that I want to ignore (under "Task Sequences").

I can get all task sequences using

```
select * from SMS_TaskSequencePackage
```

but there is no location under any of the properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not good at writing C#, but we can surely using PowerShell and WMI query to get objects in a specific folder.

Before that, we need to know the **ContainerNodeID** of the specific folder first. There are plenty of ways to get it.  For example, we use query:

```
$node = Get-WmiObject -Namespace ROOT\SMS\SITE_pri -class sms_objectcontainernode | Where-Object {$_.name -eq "folder1"}  
$nodeID = $node.containerNodeID
```

Then we can get all objects within this node by using below lines. The **20** is task sequence folder type.

```
$items = Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\sms\site_pri -Class sms_objectcontaineritem | Where-Object {$_.objectType -eq '20' -and $_.containerNodeID -eq $nodeID }
```

Here we get all objects within Folder1. If we want to get all task sequence properties in this folder, we can add below:

```
$key = $items.instancekey
$tasksequences = Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\sms\site_pri -class sms_tasksequencepackage | Where-Object {$_.packageID -in $key}
$tasksequences
```

So all the full script is:(change the foldername and siteID)

```
$node = Get-WmiObject -Namespace ROOT\SMS\SITE_pri -class sms_objectcontainernode | Where-Object {$_.name -eq "folder1"} 
$nodeID = $node.containerNodeID
$items = Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\sms\site_pri -Class sms_objectcontaineritem | Where-Object {$_.objectType -eq '20' -and $_.containerNodeID -eq $nodeId }
$key = $items.instancekey
$tasksequences = Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\sms\site_pri -class sms_tasksequencepackage | Where-Object {$_.packageID -in $key}
$tasksequences
```

Comment: Thanks thats helped loads and ive managed to target only the task sequences i need. By getting the IDs from querying sms_objectcontainernode and sms_objectcontaineritem i was then able to get the PackageIds.